# Malware Testing on a Virtual Box

Tags: malware, penetration-test

I would like to test some malware on a virtual box but I can not seem to figure out a safe way to get the malware on the virtual machine.

I was thinking maybe I could download it while I am on the virtual machine but that requires Internet connection from the network which I heard is not safe (malware that can attack others on the network).

I thought about downloading the malware to a usb then opening the usb file on the virtual machine but there is malware that makes that unsafe too.

I've also thought about downloading the malware to my computer then dragging and dropping then deleting on the host computer but that does not sound too safe either.

Is there any 100% safe way I can get the malware on the virtual machine without a risk or consequence?

Comment: Okay well this website is horrible. I will never come back here to ask a question again. I ask a simple question and in a few hours what do I get? A downvote and some text corrections. Absolutely pathetic. This website has a long way to go and so do its frequent users. Goodbye.

Comment: Downvotes are not personal attacks. You should never take them personally. Text corrections are common here for everyone. As for the wait time, sometimes you have to wait days. Just because a few hours go by with nothing but some text corrections does not mean you are being ignored. My guess is that you were downvoted because a question on asking how to be "100% safe" is impossible to answer. As it stands, this question lacks sufficient details to understand exactly what you need to be safe _from_. It may seem obvious to you, but we actually need to be explicitly told your threat model.

Comment: For what it's worth, someone [suggested](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/122522) the edit to make your question more readable. I approved the edit to improve your question. It's a good thing. If you actually want to leave this website and never come back, then I won't stop you. If you still do want an answer then just say so and I will ask for clarifications to make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: @ShayDans Please understand that Stack Exchange tries to have posts act as an easily readable, curated repository of questions and answers - as opposed to typical forums, which act as a host of conversations. Yes, sometimes SE is pedantic and annoying, but the goal is to produce the highest quality content and have it exist indefinitely. Please don't see edits as personal attacks - I agree that downvotes without a suggestion on how to clarify or improve the scope of your question aren't helpful and are often not helpful and feel like a slap in the face.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stay 100% secure. But you can try to be safe.
My way to do it:

1. Linux host.
2. Install cuckoo sandbox from https://cuckoosandbox.org/
3. Get an automatic report.

If you wan to do things manually, keep your infected files in a zip password protected file in the host.
Share a drive and copy to the virtual guest, disconnect the network, unzip the file and run it.